# ASP Best Practices involving saving device information for two factor authentication

Tags: asp.net, device, two-factor-authentication

Currently i'm trying to implement a device two factor authentication in which every time a user logs in, if that device wasn't recognized with the user the user will have to perform some sort of two factor authentication.

Currently i'm using `System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities` however, this is becoming a huge inconvenience because of automatic browser upgrades.  I'm curious if someone has a better method or any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: How about a combination of the user-agent string + IP address (to infer location)? If I had to guess I'd say the likes of Google do something along those lines (although perhaps a little more sophisticated). And you can potentially use cookies in there as well.

Comment: @ADyson IP's change exp with mobile devices

Comment: True, but, at least for fixed-line connections, the location/region/city info associated with them should be pretty similar, e.g. what you get from a service like https://geoiptool.com/en/ . Mobile devices is harder, I agree. I don't have the whole answer, hence a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [device cookie](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Slow_Down_Online_Guessing_Attacks_with_Device_Cookies)

It says "this user has successfully authenticated on this user agent in the past"

You probably want to include their username (or user id), a timestamp, and a random value (a nonce), and an HMAC of this info

Make sure this cookie is marked "secure" (HTTPS only) and "HttpOnly" (cannot be read by JavaScript)

Comment: Sorry for the late delay.  This is the route I took.  Ty